# Logparser - querying the remote event log

Tags: performance, event-log, logparser

How safely can I use the LogParser 2.2 utility while querying the remote server's event log, in terms of  CPU/memory/network?

I would like to perform a few event log queries on the production machines, without affecting performance of the running system.

For instance, when I run the below LogParser query:

```
SELECT QUANTIZE(TimeGenerated, 86400) AS Day, COUNT(*) AS [Total Errors] INTO     
outFile.csv FROM \\AServerIWishConnectTo\APPLICATION where message 
like '%error to seek%' GROUP BY Day ORDER BY Day ASC
```

.. would the above affect the "AServerIWishConnectTo" server a lot?

I'll add that the remote server is located in the local intranet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's really hard to say.

There are two types of network traffic generated by LogParser when you query remote event logs:

- The traffic generated by the Windows remote EventLog API, which consists basically of transfering the byte amount in that event log (Application, in your case); you can check the byte size by looking at the file at `c:\Windows\system32\winevt\Logs`
- The traffic generated to move the DLLs needed for resolution of messages: this consists of the whole DLL for each of the event sources registered in the (Application) event log

You can turn off resolution of messages by using `-fullText:OFF`, but then you won't be able to query for `message like '%error to seek%`.

As for CPU or Memory, querying a remote event log should not use any memory on the server, and a negligible amount of CPU.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer.
Do you know any web resources where one can read about the LogParser internals, as dlls the tool is using, etc?

Comment: So it's mostly about the CPU/Memory usage of the machine which is querying the remote server and the network traffic.

Comment: Correct, CPU and memory are mostly consumed on the machine that runs LogParser and the query. As for Web resources on internals, I don't believe there are any - in any case, LogParser just uses standard Windows API, nothing special.